# Cannot get the draw function to work in Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a completed tic-tac toe game, but I cannot seem to get a tie alert to come up in the event of a draw.

I tried adding multiple different statements at the end of the else in function checkWin, but so far I'm out of luck.

I'm not sure where to set this fix. I have tried `$("#gameboard fa-times, #gameboard fa-circle-o").length == 9` to see if perhaps that could work with an alert afterwards.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tic-Tac-Toe!</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"> -->


  <!-- CSS
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">



</head>
<body>
<h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>
<div id = "gameboard">
  <div class= "row">
    <div class = "square bottom right sq1"></div>
    <div class = "square bottom right sq2"></div>
    <div class = "square bottom sq3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class= "row">
    <div class = "square bottom right sq4"></div>
    <div class = "square bottom right sq5"></div>
    <div class = "square bottom sq6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class= "row">
    <div class = "square right sq7"></div>
    <div class = "square right sq8"></div>
    <div class = "square sq9"></div>
  </div>
  <button id ="reset" type ="reset">reset</button>







</div>
</body>


<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/703129f3e9.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my JS below. I am also using skeleton and jquery

```
//use doc.ready to wrap functions after page loads
$(document).ready(function(){
    //create a player 1 to test
    var player = 1;

    //make a click event for the class sqaures
    $('.square').on("click", function(event){

        //store the square class into $(this)
        var squareSelected = $(this);
        //make an if else statenent that adds the class "x" || "o" to your html to show it has been already selected
        if(squareSelected.hasClass("fa fa-times fa-4x") || squareSelected.hasClass("fa fa-circle-o fa-4x")){
            alert("you have clicked here already!")
        } else {
            //when square has been selected by player 1 set the player to 2;vice versa
            if(player===1){
                squareSelected.addClass("fa fa-times fa-4x");
                if (checkWin("fa fa-times fa-4x")){
                    alert("Congrats! Player " + player + " has WON!")
                } else {
                player = 2;
                }
            } else {
                squareSelected.addClass("fa fa-circle-o fa-4x");
                if (checkWin("fa fa-circle-o fa-4x")){
                    alert("Congrats! Player " + player + " has WON!")
                } else {
                player = 1;

                } 
            }
            //added a reset button that reloads the page 
            $("#reset").on("click",function(){
                location.reload();
            });
        }
    });


    //check if player won
    //if player has 3 across,3 up/down, or 3 diagnal they win
    function checkWin(symbol){
        if($(".sq1").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq2").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq3").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else if($(".sq4").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq6").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else if($(".sq7").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq8").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq9").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else if($(".sq1").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq4").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq7").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else if($(".sq2").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq8").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else if($(".sq3").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq6").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq9").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else if($(".sq1").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq9").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else if($(".sq3").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) && $(".sq7").hasClass(symbol)){
            return true
        } else {

            //cannot get draw alert to work
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your javascript code??

Comment: yes everything works perfectly except for that

Comment: Does hasClass accept more than one class in the string? As in are you sure you want `squareSelected.hasClass("fa fa-times fa-4x") ` and not `squareSelected.hasClass("fa-times") ` (and the same for circle)?

Comment: You also do the same thing inside checkwin, so that might be part of the issue. It's looking for the wrong class. Furthermore checkwin returns true/false based on how you're using it in your code, there isn't any possible way for a draw to be recognized. You would either need checkwin to return something more useful or have checkwin handle what happens when a player wins or draws.

Comment: unfortunately thats the proper class names to pull icons from font awesome

Comment: @KhauriMcClain when the player wins it gives and alert. That goes for both player 1 and 2. I have been fiddling with it and going outside these functions breaks the code for some reason